# Intellij Correct Indention

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

I know that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> will do the auto indention. However I want the indention to indent it correctly. Like for example:

```
<div>
    <div>
        Some text here.
    </div
</div>
```

But in IntelliJ. In some cases the indention is like this:

```
<div>
<div>
    Some text here.
</div
</div>
```

In NetBeans, it's indenting correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open settings, then go to Code Style you'll see a scheme drop-down, with a `Manage` button next to it. Click the button, then on the popup click `Save As` and give the scheme a meaningful name (I always use my initials, but that's up to you). In the left-panel you can 'open' the Code Style options and choose the language you're having issues with (in this case it looks like html).

The specific options you're looking for may then be found on the `Other` tab on the right.

[image]

You should play with the values here until you get the formatting you want. I think that you'll get some way towards your goals by changing the `Do not indent children of` option.